# When Auto Loggingin, Getting Error FirebaseException Was Thrown Building KeyedSubTree

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I have been struggling with this error for a while and don't know how to fix it at all. The error that is being thrown is:

```
The following FirebaseException was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#a1dff]:
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

I have initialized the firebase app already, so I am really confused why this is happening. Some things that I have tried:

**Checked my dependencies in PubSpec.yaml**

**Rerun my code and stopped the application and started it again**

**Asked ChatGPT for help (useless)**

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/Sign_Up_Screens/screen1.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/login.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Main();
}

class Main extends State<HomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String? uid;
  String? name;
  String? userEmail;
  String? imageUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    start();
  }

  void start() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? authSignedIn = prefs.getBool('auth');
    print(authSignedIn);

    final User? user = _auth.currentUser;

    if (authSignedIn == true) {
      if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid;
        name = user.displayName;
        userEmail = user.email;
        imageUrl = user.photoURL;
        prefs.setString('name', name!);
        prefs.setString('id', uid!);
      }
    }
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold (
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(57, 62, 70, 1),
      body: Container (
      height: size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget> [
          Positioned(
            top: size.height * .2,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/logos/logo.png",
              width: size.width * .8
            )
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: size.height * .65,
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'Welcome Back!',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)
                )
              ]
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: size.height * .72,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: size.width * .9,
              height: size.height * .08,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(99),
                    )
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
                ),
                child: const Text('Sign Up',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(_createRouteToSignUp());
                }, 
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: size.height * .81,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: size.width * .9,
              height: size.height * .08,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(99),
                    )
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color.fromRGBO(43, 46, 51, 1)),
                ),
                child: const Text('Log In',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(_createRouteToLogin());
                }, 
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: size.height * .96,
            left: size.width * .71,
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Text('Version 1.0.0.0',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                ),
              ]
            )
          ),
        ]
      )
    ));
  }
}

Route _createRouteToLogin() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => login_page(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

Route _createRouteToSignUp() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => screen1(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue, you need to initialize your firebase in the void main or you need to use FutureBuilder to wait until you firebase initialization finish.

Eg:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(Main());
}
```

OR

EG:

```
FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize Flutter Firebase
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return Main();
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return Loading();
      },
    );
```

Comment: Do you mind rewriting the answer in terms of my functions? Like my start() function? Because I am unsure what myApp() is.

Comment: Answer updated still You can try first eg rather than 2nd.

Comment: I tried it but an error keeps occuring. I think I am doing it wrong. Do you mind updating your answer and include my full code? So the eg part in my code? Thanks! That should be it and after it runs successfully I will mark your answer accepted and upvote.

Comment: 1st Answer will work for you. Everyone have main.dart file and void main. So, you just need to add that in your void main.

Comment: I managed to figure it out somehow using chatGpt, but thanks!